# Absolute convergence of $\sum_{t=1}^\infty t^2 e^{-\sqrt{L\ln t}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the infinite series $\sum_{t=1}^\infty t^2 e^{-\sqrt{L\ln t}}$ converge for
any value of the constant L?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** If $t$ is large enough, $\sqrt{L\ln t}\lt \ln t$. It follows that $e^{-\sqrt{L\ln t}} \gt \dots$.